# Semaphore and thread issue

Tags: java, multithreading, semaphore

After reading about semaphores I tried this test code in which I create two threads A and B. My aim is, let thread A wait for 10 secs for some operation in Thread B to complete. But as I changed the logic in thread B a little , by introducing an infinite while loop which never comes out , the Thread A is also hanging, and the program runs forever. Can anybody help me how to achieve the goal which I am looking for?

package pack;

```
import java.util.concurrent.Semaphore;

public class Concurrency {
    public int count = 0;

  public static void main(String args[]) throws Exception {
    final Semaphore sem = new Semaphore(1, true);
    Thread thrdA, thrdB;
    thrdA = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (sem) {
                try {
                    sem.wait(10000);
                    System.out.println("thread1");
                } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }

        }
    });
    thrdB = new Thread(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            synchronized (sem) {
                System.out.println("thread2");

                while(true){

                }
            }

        }
    });

    thrdA.start();
    thrdB.start();

    thrdA.join();
    thrdB.join();

  }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using a `Semaphore` if you're never `acquire()`ing and then `release()`ing it? You could have just used a `private final Object` for that purpose.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Glowcoder is correct - this runs forever because your threads aren't doing anything useful.  thrdA is waiting for the semaphore, thrdB is looping forever doing nothing - it should be doing something to the semaphore at some point so that thrdA can get past the wait.

Answer (score 2):

There are many issues in your code.

1. As mentioned in comments and answers, you if you want wait/notify you don't have to use `Semaphore`.
2. `while(true)` puts heavy load to the CPU. Consider using `Thread.sleep`, or acquiring a semaphore/lock.
3. You need to elaborate more about what you want to achieve. If you want the threadB wait for threadA you don't need any semaphore/lock. Just call `thread1.join()` before doing any other calls in `thread2.run`.

Comment: 1.yeah I agree that while(true) is a lot of CPU load, but this is just an experimental code, which I wrote, to see what happens if the second thread hangs, and the first thread waiting for second timeouts after 10 secs.
2. Also I cannot use Thread.sleep in my code due to some restrictions.

Answer (score 0):

i have been looking for semaphore and multithreading solution everywhere on net but was not able to find anything which stops Thread Generation and Memory occupancy. i.e. if there is a billion data and you just need to process 10 threads each using 10000 data at a single time i was not getting better solutions. so i wrote below code to get correct answers.

using this semaphore.availablePermits i was able to hault main thread from creating new threads and memory occupy. if you got any better solution than this kindly let me know. i have testing if for 500 Million data and it significantly inproved the performance.

```
public void startTestSemaphore() {
    ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
    Semaphore semaphore = new Semaphore(5);
    int count = 1;
    try {
        while (true) {
            if (count == 1000000) {
                break;
            }

            List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
            while (count % 100 != 0) {
                list.add(count + "SHSH");
                count++;
            }

            System.out.println(list.size());
            if (!list.isEmpty()) {
                System.out.println("Creatinng new THREAD ");
                Thread t1 = new Thread(new Runnable() {
                    @Override
                    public void run() {
                        try {
                            semaphore.acquire();
                            System.out.println("EXECUTING THREAD " + Thread.currentThread().getName());
                            TestClassSem sem1 = new TestClassSem();
                            sem1.callThread();
                        } catch (InterruptedException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } finally {
                            semaphore.release();
                        }
                    }
                });
                executor.execute(t1);
                count++;
            }

            while(semaphore.availablePermits()==0) {
                Thread.sleep(2000);
                System.out.println(Thread.currentThread().getName()+" is sleeping bcz other threads are executing");
            }
        }
        executor.shutdown();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            executor.awaitTermination(1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
        } catch (InterruptedException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```